use range with custom field
In my Kusto/ADX Timeseries Database i have a custom timestamp field because the ingestion process takes quite a bit and i need the exact time for my entries.
Now i want to query results with a certain resolution (i.e. 1 Minute Averages over 15 Minutes), so i would use range.
But range uses the insert timestamp if i understand it correctly.
Can i make range use my custom timestamp (of type datetime) field?

Can you explain your requirement with a sample input and expected output? and please provide the code that you have tried so far?

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return the average of a certain value in 1-minute timeframes. Assuming your table is structured like this, you can use the below query to get the average value per 1-minute timeframe.



Column name
Data type
Description




MyCustomTimestamp
Timestamp
Your custom timestamp value


Value
Integer
The value that you want the average of in 1-minute timeframes



Table structure for TableName
TableName
// Query only the last 15 minutes of data
| where MyCustomTimestamp > ago(15m)
// Using the bin() function to round the timestamp down to 1 minute
| summarize Average = avg(Value) by Timeframe = bin(MyCustomTimestamp, 1m)

The query broken down into steps:

Query only data where MyCustomTimestamp is greater than 'now - 15 minutes'
Introduce a new column called Timeframe which is equal to the MyCustomTimestamp value rounded down to the nearest full minute. I.e. 12:04:33 is rounded down to 12:04:00
Calculate the average of Value for every column that falls within the same 1 minute (summarize by Timeframe).

